# Different behavior of node server if executed from terminal or from npm bin command

Tags: node.js, express, npm, bin

So I've made a proxy nodejs server that executes a python library when called.

If I run the server directly from the terminal, and then execute a call to the server, I get the correct behavior: my calling scripts waits for the server response, and I get the expected result.

Now the idea of this server is to make a package (A) that I can call from another package (B).

For that, I'm using the `bin` option of package.json of package A.

```
"bin": {
  "issuer": "bin/index.js"
}
```

The idea is that the consuming package (B) would start the server (`issuer start &`) and then do whatever it needs to do with said server.

The index.js is a entry script to make the CLI nicer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const { exec } = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');

const command = process.argv[2];

if (command === 'help') {
  console.log(`
  Main invocation: issuer
  Available commands:
    - help: show help
    - start: start proxy server to python issuer
    - stop: stop server
  `)
  return;
}

if (command === 'start') {
  exec(`node ${path.join(__dirname, './start-server.js')}`, {
    cwd: path.join(__dirname, '..')
  }, (err) => {
    if (err){
      console.error(err);
    }
  });
  return;
}

if (command === 'stop') {
  exec(`node ${path.join(__dirname, './kill-server.js')}`, {
    cwd: path.join(__dirname)
  }, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  });
  return;
}

console.log('issuer unknown command', command, 'run `issuer help` for a list of available commands');
```

and start-server.js is a simple express server creation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const issue = require('./middlewares/issue');
const server = express();
const port = require('./port');

server.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));

server.post('/issue', issue);

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`issuer-node-wrapper app listening at http://localhost:${port}`));
```

But 2 things are not working using that entry script:

- There is no stdout, so I don't see the output `issuer-node-wrapper app listening at http://localhost:${port}`. But the server is indeed started (port is taken, `lsof -t -i:3000` gives me a pid I can later kill). If I change the bin to run the js script directly, ie `issuer-start: ./bin/start-server.js`, I do see the console log output, but I would rather have a command with arguments.
- in both cases, when I later execute a call to the server (`http://localhost:3000/issue`), the response comes immediately and the response parsing fails with:

```
Error: FetchError: invalid json response body at http://localhost:3000/issue reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

From I can tell, this is because the Promise is not properly terminated when it executes the `then` part, so it's actually parsing `<Pending>` (hence the `<` invalid character error):

```
const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/issue', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      certificates,
      ...issuerPath && {
        issuerPath
      }
    }),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  }).then(res => {
    const decoded = res.json(); <<<< HERE
    return decoded;
  }).catch (err => {
    // throw new Error(err);
    console.error('Error:', err);
  });
```

So there must be something I don't understand at a low-level and cannot find the reason why, when `exec` or `spawn` the server from the bin command, which would somehow make the server lost in a different thread, or something?

My question is, what is actually going on when I am running `npm "bin"` that makes the server behave differently, although started?

Comment: You're returning the promise returned by `res.json()`; it needs to be awaited.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,

the issue was that the `cwd` or execution context was not properly taken into account by the execution script on the server which was using `__dirname`.

So the issue was between the chair and the screen rather than with node itself.